# How to exclude show filters for specific endpoint in drf-yasg

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I have some ViewSet with `filterset_fields` and `ordering_fields` attributes. Also i have extra action in that ViewSet, that uses as a shortcut to get list with some filtration. I assume to use that extra action without handling any additional filter(or may be ordering) options. But in default way drf-yasg genereates parameters schema for that extra action with `filterset_fields` and `ordering_fields`.

How i can ignore `filterset_fields` and `ordering_fields` attributes for specific endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your action decorator set **filterset_fields** and **ordering_fields** to an empty list:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], filterset_fields=[], ordering_fields=[], search_fields=[])
```

You can go even further and disable **filter_backends**:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], filter_backends=[])
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research i'm do that:

```
from drf_yasg.inspectors import SwaggerAutoSchema

class MySwaggerAutoSchema(SwaggerAutoSchema):
    def get_query_parameters(self):
        return []
```

And use that subclass in `swagger_auto_schema` decorator for my extra action that way  `@swagger_auto_schema(auto_schema=MySwaggerAutoSchema)`.

But it looks barbaric. If anyone has a more elegant solution - let me know.